# How to avoid "input string is not in correct format" error when passing a null value

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a class that I am passing a value too from my textbox. I use int? in the class I am passing too, to allow null values. Every-time I execute it gives the input string is not in correct format error. How can I get it to allow the null value? I thought about creating an if statement that just passes string = "null". I put my code below thank you in advance.

This is what I use to pass the values to my class that gives the error when I leave it blank.

```
newGrid.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(employeeIDTextBox.Text);
newGrid.JobID = Convert.ToInt32(JobIDTextBox.Text);
```

Variable declaration in my class that the info is passing to.

```
public int? JobID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `TryParse` instead:

```
Int32 employeeId;
newGrid.EmployeeID = Int32.TryParse( employeeIDTextBox.Text, out employeeId ) ? employeeId : null;
```

This does require multiple lines of statements. You could wrap `TryParse` to simplfy this, like so:

```
public static Int32? Int32TryParseSafe(String text) {
    Int32 value;
    return Int32.TryParse( text, out value ) ? value : null;
}

// Usage:
newGrid.EmployeeID = Int32TryParseSafe( employeeIDTextBox.Text );
```

Comment: Ok so use the second method or both?

Comment: Error 1 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and '<null>'

Comment: I got it needed (int?) ex: ? (int?)value

Answer (score 1):

```
      int number;
      bool result = Int32.TryParse(employeeIDTextBox.Text, out number);
      if (result)
      {
         newGrid.EmployeeID=number;       
      }
      else
      {
      //whatever you want to do for bad values
      newGrid.EmployeeID=0;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to convince `Convert.ToInt32` to change its behavior, but you can easily get the effect you want yourself:

```
string employeeID = employeeIDTextBox.Text;
newGrid.EmployeeID = string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeID) ? null : Convert.ToInt32(employeeID);
```

Note that while this is less verbose than some other options, you aren't as safe as you are with `TryParse`. If the user enters non-numeric characters this will fail.